# Random id generation inside ngFor

Tags: angular

I am trying to generate unique id for each even `<tr>`. The idea is to use a random text along with the index, example `idtext = "grid" + index`. In the below code everything is working except for `idtext`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index; let idtext = 'grid' + index;">
  <tr class="clickable" [attr.data-index]="item.num" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#idtext" class="accordion-toggle">
    <td>{{index}}{{item.num}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    <td> Demo </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="4"  class="hiddenRow">
        <div id="idtext" class="accordian-body collapse">Demo3</div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

How do I fix this issue ?

Comment: have a method on the component that generates the id and call it from the template. Also post a minimal working code on a plunkr

Comment: Solved it like this `attr.id="{{'grid'+index}}"`